# Deployed Spring-Boot war doesn't work in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I deployed my Spring-Boot application with Java8 into Tomcat 8.5, but when I'm sending some request using CURL, I get a 404 response. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not new to Java, but it's my first time to set up an environment on a server to deploy my app. The blog post I followed: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/

The only difference is that I installed Tomcat 8.5 on a Ubuntu 16.04 and I didn't set up the manager interface.

My Spring-Boot entry point:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>
        some.group.id
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>
        server
    </artifactId>
    <!--<version>-->
        <!--1.0-SNAPSHOT-->
    <!--</version>-->

    <properties>
        <commons-lang.version>3.6</commons-lang.version>
        <guava.version>25.0-jre</guava.version>
        <jwt.version>0.9.0</jwt.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.9.9</joda-time.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>2.17.0</mockito.version>
        <start-class>some.group.id.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-testlib</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>
                    org.springframework.boot
                </groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    spring-boot-maven-plugin
                </artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm starting Tomcat as a service:

```
Description=Tomcat 8 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcatuser
Group=tomcatuser

#Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djava.awt.headless=true"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

JAVA_HOME is set in the /etc/environment, so that's why it's commented out.

I deployed my App to AWS, and it works. When I'm running it locally from IntelliJ, it also works. So, I assume it has to do with my Tomcat setup. Also, I do not have any log files, such as catalina.out.

Comment: `404` means the tomcat is up and running but it didn't find any mapping to the url you requested. It is possible that you are requesting `http:localhost:8080/my-cool-url` but maybe you're running your spring app under `my-app` context route, so in this case you should have requested `http:localhost:8080/my-app/my-cool-url`. It's hard to tell with the current info. But I recommend you to try to access the web manager provided by Tomcat and see if you can access the app through it.

Comment: *"I do not have any log files, such as catalina.out"* Then start by fixing that, so you can see the any error messages explaining why your webapp might have failed to start.

Comment: @lealceldeiro, what a mistake from me. It was the "my-app" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@lealceldeiro answer helped me

The error was that I was requesting a resource without the name of my application's context route. My deployed war was "app.war" named, so, the wrong URL which I was requesting:

`host-address:8080/resource-uri`

The right URL is:

`host-address:8080/app/resource-uri`

Comment: Why do you need to install tomcat on the server? Spring Boot 'spring-boot-starter-web' has the own one(embedded tomcat). All you need is to run your app as "java -jar app.war"

Comment: Glad my comment helped you. Remember you can [accept this post as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) even if [it is one of your own posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @lealceldeiro, yes, I know. But I get a pop-up: *You can accept your own answer in 2 days.* So I'll wait 2 days :)

Comment: @ОлегГаврилів, I was a little bit in a hurry, so I didn't research it. But thanks for that tip, I will take a look on that too.